# How to add app page to test app of instant game?

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-games

I want to add one app page to my test version of instant game, following this page [Setting up your bot](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/getting-started/bot-setup),

> - The page's category needs to be App Page
> - The page's name needs to contain the name of the app.
> - The page cannot be associated with another app.
>
> You can create a page with these special conditions by going to the **App Page** section of the Instant Games product in your App dashboard. Before moving on to the next step, make sure that your App Page section looks like the step on the right:

After create one app page. I can find the app page section in the **origin app dashboard**, which under the `Settings -> Advanced`

[image]

However I failed to find the test app page section in app dashboard.

[image]

[image]

Is there any restrict of test version of instant game app? How can I add app page for test version of instant game?

Comment: Have you solved it? If not I can help you now.

Comment: @Sparsh, I appreciate if you post your answer, thank you every much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can create app page for the instant game from **Settings > Advanced** Or **Instant Game > Details**. Both are same things. **Create New Page** takes you to choose the page category. Get started with **Business or Brand**. Page Name is very **important**. The page's name needs to contain the name of the app.

**Name your page name such that it exactly matches your app name.**

From the image here for eg: **Zangw's App**
[image]

Next important (where you might have missed), **Set the page category App Page.**
[image]

Finally, reload the App dashboard and you will see the dropdown section like below:[image]